# AS3 | How to remove letters drom string and remain only integer

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How to remove letters drom string and remain only integer?

Example:
input: item_Maps_4
output: 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex on your string:

```
var str:String = "item_Maps_4";
str = str.replace( /[a-zA-Z\_]/g, "" );
```

That will get rid of all the letters and underscores

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number from output(question is not clear) then you can do

```
var value:String=text.split(":")[1];
```

you may need to trim the result and if you need it as an int use parseInt function